# update xml file using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have simple XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <device>
        <node>1</node>
        <name>Deposit</name>
        <description>Server</description>
        <area>Saloon</area>
        <type>Server</type>
    </device>
</config>
```

and i have Ajax which is loading xml:

```
function  changename(node2){
    var nodenumber = node2
    var newname = "newname"     
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "config2.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {

                $(xml).find('device').each(function () {

                    var node = $(this).find('node');
                    if (node.text() == nodenumber) {
                        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                        alert(name);
                    }   
                });             
            }
        });
    }
```

What i need to do is update name in XML. I need to put newname variable value there.
This code only alert old name. Now i need to update xml file new name which is in newname variable.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

use the same function which allows you to get the old name value:

```
var xml = $(xml);
xml.find('device').each(function () {

    var node = $(this).find('node');
    if (node.text() == nodenumber) {
        $(this).find('name').text(newname);
    }
});
```

you can also change whole your code in the `success` callback to this:

```
var xml = $(xml);
var node = xml.find('device>node')
    .filter(function(index, node){ return ($(node).text()==nodenumber); })
    .parent().find(">name").text(newname);
```

the point is it is now changed, but only in what you have in `xml` variable, and if you create another jQuery object, it has the old value.

Consider that it is a client side change (just in browser) in a xml document which is a JavaScript object, after you made your changes in it you should `POST` it to your server side, and override the new changed xml over the old version.

Comment: its not working ? is it possible to test this on localhost or i need to have a server ?